# Testing image file upload using mocha and sinon (NodeJS)

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-storage, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to write an integration test to test for image upload to google cloud storage. I am using cloud storage emulator.
Here are the code below:

controller.ts

```
export class UserProfileController {
constructor(public repo: UserProfileRepository) {}

uploadProfilePic = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
    
        const { email } = res.locals.decoded_token

        var bucket = this.repo.storage.bucket('profile_pictures')
        const blob = bucket.file(req.file?.originalname as string)
        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
            resumable: false
        })
        blobStream.on('error', e => {
            throw e
        })
        .on('finish', async () => {
            const publicUrl = format(
                `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
            )
            try {
                await this.repo.setProfilePicUrl(email, publicUrl)
                return new APIResponse(res).success(publicUrl)
            } 
            catch (e) {
                return next(e)
            }
            
        })
        .end(req.file?.buffer)
    } 
    catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
```

controller.test.ts

```
describe('controller: user-profile', () => {

beforeEach(async function () {
    repo = new UserProfileRepository(firestore, storage)
    controller = new UserProfileController(repo)
})

describe('', () => {

    let onStub: SinonStub
    beforeEach(async function () {
        await clearDatabase()
        onStub = sinon.stub(internal.Writable.prototype, 'on')
            .callsArgWith(1, new Error())
            .callsArgWith(1)
        await addMockUsers()
    
    })

    afterEach(async function () {
        onStub.restore()
        return await clearDatabase()
    })

    it('should upload image to storage bucket', async () => {

        const req = {
            file: {
                originalname: 'fake-name',
                buffer: 'fake-buffer'
            }
        } as any

        const res = {
            status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
            json: sinon.stub(),
            locals: {
                decode_token: {
                    email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
                }
            }
        } as any
        
        const next = sinon.stub()

        await controller.uploadProfilePic(req, res, next)

        const user = await getDoc('users', { key: 'email', value: 'johndoe@gmail.com' })
        const profilePicPath = user.profile_pic_path

        console.log(profilePicPath)

        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.status, 200)
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.json, { status: 'success', data: profilePicPath, message: null })
    })

})
```

Code for APIResponse

```
export class APIResponse {
constructor (public res: Response) {}

success(data: any, msg: string | null = null, code: number = 200) {
    return this.res.status(code).json({status: 'success', data: data, message: msg})
}
error (msg: string | null, code: Omit<HttpStatusCode, 'OK'> = HttpStatusCode.INTERNAL_SERVER, data: any = null,) {
    this.res.status(code as number).json({status: 'error', data: data, message: msg})
}
```

}

`format` was retrieved from nodeJS `util` package

Sample code was derived from thus [google cloud sample](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage#application_code)

Test fails with

> AssertError: expected stub to be called with exact arguments

How do I modify the test to work? How the I specify the exact file to be uploaded by just using the `req` object?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please provide the code of `APIResponse` and `format`

Comment: @slideshowp2, I have just made an edit to the post

Comment: The problem is with the structure of your code. Please check this post of someone that had                                                                                                    
[similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963244/assertionerror-expected-stub-to-have-been-called-with-arguments-201) with the code.